# Быстрый пересчет CRC32

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, хеширование, crc

имеется такая проблема: надо быстро (худший вариант за O(log N)) пересчитать CRC32 массива. Дан массив и 4 измененных ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНЫХ байта. Где-то вычитал идею с бинарным возведением в степень, но так и не смог развить. Было бы замечательно, если бы вы привели пример на псевдокоде или ЯП, с пояснением что и как. Заранее спасибо!

UPD:
Мы умеем это делать быстрее, чем за линейное время(для последовательности длины > 400), одна проблема: это слишком медленно.

Как это можно сделать? Давайте предположим, что за log(n) * const мы умеем мержить два CRC32 в один. В таком случае, давайте построим ДО, и массив префиксов изначальных CRC32. В таком случае, за O(4) мы получим значение CRC32 на отрезке [0; i+3], за log^2*const на отрезке [i+4; n-1]. И смержим их в один.
Смежная проблема: можно ли как-то быстро посчитать массив суффиксов CRC32 для данной последовательности? Формально, такой массив `suff`, что `suff[i]=CRC32(a, i, n-1)`, где `CRC32(array, left, right)` - CRC32 на отрезке от `left` до `right` в массиве `array`.

Comment: Очевидно, что это невозможно.

Comment: байта или бита измененных?

Comment: байта. на счет невозможности могу поспорить - есть вариант на англоязычном stackoverflow, который предлагает log(n) раз перемножать матрицы 32x32, что явно дольше, чем log(n)

Comment: вот много быстрых реализаций https://create.stephan-brumme.com/crc32/

Comment: @becouse, не за линейное время. И вообще, лучше бы без сторонних библиотек, с минимальным кол-вом кода.

Comment: Читал когда-то статейку, в ней обратная задача решалась - как изменить 4 байта, чтоб получить нужный CRC32. Увы, ничего не помню...

Comment: Как поменять 4 байта чтобы получить нужный CRC32 - ясно, я тоже её прочитал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а Вы говорили, что это невозможно :)

Comment: Блин.. Я вопрос не понял. Я думал, надо определить, какие 4 байта изменены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, решение за `O(log(n) * 32)`, где n - длина последовательности после измененных байт.
Для начала, давайте обратимся к [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601950/how-to-recalculate-a-crc32-on-a-large-byte-array-when-replacing-a-small-number-o/). Посмотрим замечательную реализацию функции `crc32_combine` от `zlib`. Она медленная - `O(log(n) * 32 * 32)` - перемножение матриц долгое. Для начала, заметим, что мы каждый раз просто перемножаем одни и те же матрицы, таким образом, мы можем взять два массива матриц, которые мы предпосчитаем заранее. Таким образом, асимптотика решения быстро сокращается в 32 раза. Для начала, расскажу, что делает `crc32_combine`. Она берет crc32 первой последовательности и "сдвигает" её на `len2` байт. Таким образом, если мы меняли байт `i`, и знаем crc32 для отрезка [0; i] = `crc1`, и знаем новый crc32 для того же отрезка = `crc2`, ответом будет являться `crc32_combine(crc1 ^ crc2, original_crc, n - i - 1)`, где `original_crc` - оригинальный crc32 последовательности. Каким образом предпосчитать массивы матриц? Давайте эмулировать crc32_combine.

```
#define GF2_DIM 32 

uint32_t odd[32][32];
uint32_t even[32][32];
unsigned long gf2_matrix_times(
    uint32_t* mat,
    uint32_t vec)
{
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    while (vec) {
        if (vec & 1)
            sum ^= *mat;
        vec >>= 1;
        ++mat;
    }
    return sum;
}


void gf2_matrix_square(
    uint32_t* square,
    uint32_t* mat)
{
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < GF2_DIM; n++)
        square[n] = gf2_matrix_times(mat, mat[n]);
}
void precalc() {
    uint32_t even1[GF2_DIM] = { 1996959894, 3993919788, 124634137, 249268274, 498536548, 997073096, 1994146192, 3988292384, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, };    /* even-power-of-two zeros operator */
    uint32_t odd1[GF2_DIM] = { 498536548, 997073096, 1994146192, 3988292384, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728, };     /* odd-power-of-two zeros operator */
    uint32_t i = 0;
    do {
        if (i)
            gf2_matrix_square(even1, odd1);
        for (int j = 0; j < GF2_DIM; j++) 
            even[i][j] = even1[j];
        gf2_matrix_square(odd1, even1);
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j < GF2_DIM; j++)
            odd[i][j] = odd1[j];
        i++;
    } while (i < 32);
}

uint32_t crc32_update(
    uint32_t crc1,
    uint32_t crc2,
    size_t len2)
{
    uint32_t n;
    uint32_t row;
    int step = 0;
    do {
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(even[step], crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;
        step++;
        if (!len2)
            break;
        if (len2 & 1)
            crc1 = gf2_matrix_times(odd[step], crc1);
        len2 >>= 1;
        step++;
    } while (len2);
    return crc1 ^ crc2;
}
```

Как быстро считать новый crc32 измененной последовательности за O(длина последовательности)? Давайте предпосчитаем префиксы crc32.
**UPD:** можно сократить объем памяти в два раза, путём деление шага на два при подсчете мержа CRC32.